# How do I run an executable file with a double click?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I'm trying to run an executable (testdisk) but double click doesn't work. The only way is to run:

```
sudo ./testdisk
```

from terminal. But I'd like to open executables with double click in future. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

[image]Right click on the file ,and check the Allow executing file as program button  in permission tab

Then Double click on the file and choose run or run in terminal(If it is a console application )

**Note:**

*This wont work if program need root permission*

Comment: 'answered 9 secs ago' great minds think alike?

Answer (score 4):

To run an application by double clicking it's icon we have to define a `.desktop` file stored in the location from where we want to start it (e.g. on the `~/Desktop/`).

The minimal content of such a file may be similar to the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application    
Exec=/path/to/executable  --options # commands to run
Icon=/path/to/icon # optional path to the icon
Terminal=false # set `true' for terminal applications
```

Save this file on the desired location and give it `executable` permission.

Side note: it is not really a good idea to run your example application Testdisk by a double click from the GUI.

Answer (score 4):

Open the file manager or nautilus. 
Go to **Edit->Preferences**.

- Under the behavior tab, click/enable the 3rd option --**"ask each time"** for "executable text files".
- Or use **"run executable files when they are opened"**